# Integration testing ,how to find whether the dropdown elements are activated one or not

Tags: qtp

pls help me out from my doub't in qtp how to check whether the elements which are in dropdown option is activated one or not.

example i have 2 pages state and city,in state page i have deactivated some state that shouldn't in city page how to write code through DP .

Answer (score 0):

You should get item from a first drop down menu and compare with the other one. For example:

```
For i = 1 To 5
city = Browser("").WebList("").GetItem(i)

For j = 1 To 5
state = Browser("").WebList("").GetItem(j)
If state = city Then
  MsgBox("True")
Else
  MsgBox("False")
End If
Next
Next
```

Just adjust for cycle or body :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are deactivating a specific state in State Page

```
State_Page_state = "deactivated_state_name"
```

Get the list of State from the from the City page

```
ListOfStates_Page_city = Browser("").Page("City_page").WebList("state").GetROProperty("all items")
```

Search the state from the list and if present it would return the position in the list else returns 0

```
bool= InStr(1,State_Page_state,ListOfStates_Page_city)

if bool >0 Then
    msgbox "Present"
else
    msgbox "Not Present"
```